# Show custom field from another CPT

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to make a query:
I have an entry in "assessment" CPT with custom fields made with ACF, one of which is name "customer" which has the customer ID.
I want to know how to show in front-end a field of another CPT called "customers".
The custom field I also did with ACF and is name "profile_photo". The author of this CPT is the same as the ACF custom field "customer" in "assessment" CPT.

I think it would be something like that ... I don't know if I'm on the right track.

```
function the_field_by_author( $field, $author ) {
  $user_info = get_field( "customer" ); 
  $args = [
    'post_author'    => $user_info->ID,
    'post_type'      => 'clientes', 
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
  ];
  $my_post = get_posts( $args );
  if( $my_post ) {
    return get_field( "photo_profile", $my_post->ID );
  }
   }

add_shortcode('shortcode_the_field_by_author', 'the_field_by_author');
```

I'm new and I don't know how to display the custom field in each "assessment" entry.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Manuel please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You could start with the SQl query to achieve the above.

Answer (score 1):

The method is actually the same as what you would do with default post types such as posts. You can use the **get_field** or the **the_field** functions.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

Just make sure to use the appropriate custom post ID in the function parameter.

```
$value = get_field( "text_field", 123 );
```

Make sure that 123 is the ID of a post from the custom post type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The point is that each customer has a specific entry in the CPT "customers".
It would be cumbersome in each entry of "assessment" to manually put the id of each publication that was created.

The entries of the CPT "customers" are added automatically when creating a new user. Each entry is associated with the user ID as the "author" of the publication.

I would have to associate the ID that I keep in the custom field of the CPT "assessment" with the ID of "author" of the CPT "customers".
I don't know if I explain myself.

Comment: I think it would be something like that ... I don't know if I'm on the right track.
'function the_field_by_author( $field, $author, $cpt = 'assessment' ) {
$user_info = get_field( "customer" );
    $args = [
        'post_author'   => $user_info->ID,
        'post_type'      => $cpt,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    ];
    $my_post = get_posts( $args );
    if( $my_post ) {
        return get_field( "photo_profile", $my_post->ID );
    }
}'

Comment: You should include that code in your inquiry  for clarification. Maybe someone else has the answer.